# Looking for a command to allow a linebreak with a hyphen

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I am looking for a command like `\allowbreak` that inserts a hyphen when breaking the line at this position. So I basically only want to add a hint where to break a word and not allow splitting it into two.

Comment: What about using `aver\-ylon\-gword\-here`?

Comment: @Sigur As simple as it is, it seems to be the answer I was looking for. Do you like to make it an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you wish to explicitly give the hyphenation. You can do this locally making use of `aver\-ylon\-gword\-here` or you can define the hyphenation for some specific word on preamble with `\hyphenation{aver-ylon-gword-here}` and it will be used any time when necessary.